# Bash if -gt also triggered when values equal?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want my script to check if it's already running in another instance:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep bash
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep -c bash

if [ `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep -c bash` -gt 1 ]; then echo "There's another instance running."
else echo "Only this instance is running."
fi
```

However the output is

```
$ ./test.sh 
noes   9503  7494  0 09:32 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
1
There's another instance running.
```

Clearly, 1 is not greater than 1, so why is the if condition triggered?

Thanks

Comment: `bash` itself its a process running in your current terminal session. So it counts that likely. use `pidof` or `pgrep`

Comment: GreyCat's Wiki's [Process Management](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) is an ideal place to learn how to do this stuff.

Comment: The command substitution (the backtick expression) creates a subshell, which is *also* running test.sh, and therefore also gets counted. This sort of thing is really hard to get right; I second @l0b0's recommendation of [GreyCat's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) for better techniques.

Comment: @l0b0 Thank you for the link, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [test man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> INTEGER1 -gt INTEGER2
> INTEGER1 is greater than INTEGER2

So the answer is no, `-gt` is not triggered when values are equal. In fact, as you can see if you modify the script in this way:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep bash
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep -c bash

STRINGS=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh"`
echo "$STRINGS"
COUNT=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep -c bash`
echo $COUNT

if [ `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep -c bash` -gt 1 ]; then echo "There's another instance running."
else echo "Only this instance is running."
fi
```

You get this:

```
$ ./test.sh 
lucio     5097  4736  0 10:10 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
1
lucio     5097  4736  0 10:10 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
lucio     5106  5097  0 10:10 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
2
There's another instance running.
```

If you modify the script in this way, it will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -i "test.sh" | grep bash
pgrep -c test.sh

if [ $(pgrep -c test.sh) -gt 1 ]; then
        echo "There's another instance running."
else
        echo "Only this instance is running."
fi
```

This is the output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
lucio     5197  4736  0 10:17 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
1
Only this instance is running.
```

Note the use `$()` instead of backticks. Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated) for this change.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't get to it earlier. Thanks for your reply, I will switch to $() in the future